# Getting all Asana-Tasks (not just the non-archived ones)

Tags: api, asana

When I request my Workspace with the Asana-Api, like this:

```
curl -u <api_key>: "https://app.asana.com/api/1.0/tasks?workspace=14916&assignee=me"
```

Im not getting just the non-archived ones like written in the Documentation.
(https://asana.com/developers/api-reference/tasks in the section: QUERYING FOR TASKS)

Im wondering if I do something wrong, or if just the API sends me a wrong result.
Does anyone has the same problem?

Comment: But when you query for task included on a non-archived project, i think that there is no way to retreive all them, included non-archived ones.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to Ryan from the Asana team (Thanks for the Email support), its just the fact, that you have to archive the tasks in the right view. I archived it always in the Project-View but this seems not to be the same as in the "My Tasks View". The API request like described above looks the state of the Tasks in the "My Tasks View" up.

Ryans Answer:

> It's worth noting here how archiving works in Asana. Archiving is per
>   view/project. If I have a completed task assigned to me in Project A
>   and I archive the completed tasks in my My Tasks list, that action
>   will not archive it in Project A.